# If $T^2=T$ then $\mbox{trace}(T) = \mbox{rank}(T)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Let $T:V \rightarrow V$ be a linear transformation on a finite-dimensional vector space $V$. 
If $T$ is idempotent ($T^2=T$). Then $\mbox{trace}(T) = \mbox{rank}(T)$.

if $T$ is invertible then we have $T=1$ and the equality satisfied . but in case $T$ is not invertible I have no clue.

Comment: What are the possible eigenvalues for $T$?

Comment: in case T invertible all eigenvalues will be one.

Comment: Address the non-invertible case. Consider minimal polynomials.

Comment: we have  $g(T)=T^2-T=0$ hence $g$ divisible by minimal polynomial. not sure how this help for non-invertible case.

Comment: Note that $g(T) = T(T-I)$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:show that V is the direct summand of ker(T) and Im(T), the restriction of T to Im(T) is the identity and write the matrix of T in a basis which is the union of a basis of ker(T) and a basis of Im(T).

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $T$ is diagonalizable with eigenvalues $1$ and $0$.  So, it must be similar to a matrix of the form 
$$
\pmatrix{I_r&0\\0&0}
$$
Where $I_r$ is the $r\times r$ identity and $r$ is the rank of $T$.